# Selecting individual element within larger table on keypress in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I have a series of nested tables with tabular data.  The tables are 3 deep, so there is a master table that holds the structure of the whole thing, some intermediate tables that hold sections of the master table, and data tables that contain the actual data.

The idea is that when an element registers a key event, a calculation is made on the row of data that registered the key event.

The structure of the data tables is roughly as follows:

```
<table id="someDataTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >Some Title</td>
            <td >Units</td>
            <td >Val/Unit</td>
            <td >Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" size="30" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="14" class="units"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="14" class="value"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" size="14" readonly="readonly" class=total"/></td>
        </tr>
...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table id is unique, of course.

The rough idea is 'units * value = total' in however many rows (they are dynamically generated on demand, but I don't think that should matter).

My idea to make this possible was to capture all of the keypresses in the master table with this:

```
function initialize() {
    $(document).on('keypress', '#tblMasterTable', DoMathForRow);
}
```

Which then calls on a universal function that could do the math for all the data tables.  The idea was to use 'this' as the means of identification...

```
function DoMathForRow() {

    tKeyedBox = this;

    //Do Things Here
}
```

Basically, I was hoping 'this' would return the input box that was typed in, so I could effectively say

```
tKeyedBox.parent().parent()
```

And have access to the exact row were there was a keypress event.  From there it would be easy to do the rest.

But, 'this' returns the entire master table, which is quite unfortunate.

My question then is as follows:  How do I retrieve the input box (or cell, or row --  Something absolutely identifying) where there was a keypress event.

I'm quite new to jQuery so I'm quite mediocre at structuring my selection statements well and I feel this is probably an easy question that may have been answered in the past, but I couldn't derive the information I was looking for in the other questions.  Thanks for your patience!

Comment: tKeyedBox in your code is a global variable, i'm quite sure you would like to use a local one: var tKeyedBox = this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dig a level deeper in your selector, and only register the keypress when it's pressed on an `input`

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#tblMasterTable input[type="text"]', DoMathForRow);
```

`this` will now refer to your `input`, rather than your table.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  It worked beautifully!  Thanks!